# Sample() in R returning non-random sample after population vector length > 13. Why?

Tags: r, sample, random

The following code will return a perfectly sound sample:

```
b <- sample(c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12), 100000, replace=TRUE)
hist(b)
```

[image]

Increasing the number for elements by 1 to 14 will result into this:

```
b <- sample(c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13), 100000, replace=TRUE)
hist(b)
```

[image]

That's clearly not correct. Zero occurs more often that it should. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: Using `hist()` with discrete data is a not a good idea. Histograms are for estimating the density of continuous variables. You probably should be looking at a bar chart. Do `plot(table(b))` instead. The problem isn't with the data generation, it's with your visualization.

Comment: And [another](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23741371/324364) duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in `hist`, not in `sample`.

You can check that doing:

```
> table(sample(0:15, 10000, replace=T))

  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15 
634 642 664 654 628 598 633 642 647 625 587 577 618 645 615 591
```

From the `hist` help:

> If right = TRUE (default), the histogram cells are intervals of the
>   form (a, b], i.e., they include their right-hand endpoint, but not
>   their left one, with the exception of the first cell when
>   include.lowest is TRUE.
>
> For right = FALSE, the intervals are of the form [a, b), and
>   include.lowest means ‘include highest’.

If you try

```
hist(sample(0:15, 10000, replace=T), br=-1:15)
```

the results will look correct